# How to remove light cover

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

Does anybody have a similar light covering to this? I have tried pulling all the arms outward, pressing the arms up, looking for screws on the arms, and just sliding it out with a little bit of force. All no goes so far [image]

Comment: Do the arms rotate, to perhaps provide a lower stress exit for the glass?

Comment: Clearer, closer photos would be nice.

Comment: Does the entire fixture perhaps unscrew from the ceiling?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't come off. Looks like there may be room to replace the bulbs and even get at the screw in the middle for removal of the whole fixture without removal of the glass..

Comment: I am almost certain that one of those arms should be able to be pulled straight out enough to turn so you can slide the glass out of the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just figured out how to change this. There is 1 arm that has a bunch of give, the other 3 are pretty static. It was a 2 person job... One pushes the whole glass part up to the ceiling, while the other 'bends' the one arm up which will allow the glass to come out.

Comment: You say **"we just figured this out"**  but you are not the person who asked the question. Do you have the exact same fixture ? I can not see how the glass can be pushed up in the fixture in the photo.

Comment: This did the trick! Was able to do it with one person by pressing up and angling it into the one arm that has extra give. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the C-shaped retainers at the ends of the arms rotate. You'd turn them to horizontal.